# Opening a youtube (Intent.Action_view) link fullscreen

Tags: android, android-intent

I tried various option like:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(vnd.youtube://"+<id>);
```

But it seems like I cannot start the `Intent` in full screen forced mode.

A solution could be to do a webview. But there should be a way force full screen.

Maybe I can  fix it by adding a bundle to the `Intent`?

please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for YouTube v4.1.47, you can do the following:

```
Intent playIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
playIntent.setData(Uri.parse(<yout_YouTube_url>));
playIntent.putExtra("force_fullscreen", true);
```

It might work on older versions, but I haven't tested it.